# How to make a form_for each object in an instance variable? Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails app, each User has many graphs, each Graph has many trackables, and each Trackable has many points (with a value and time). Users are able to add (or remove) different trackables to plot vs created_at time. Users can to go to a graph's show page and submit forms to create new points for each trackable the graph has.

In the GraphController show action, I assign all the trackables of the current graph to @trackables, and then in views/graphs/show I loop through each |trackable| and attempt to make a new point for the trackable.

===============

EDIT: This is the error raised in the browser when trying to access the graph show page

**NoMethodError in Graphs#show
undefined method `trackable_points_path' for #<#:0x007fbce1548008>**

and then this line is highlighted in the Extracted source in the browser

```
- simple_form_for([trackable, trackable.points.build]) do |f|
```

================

EDIT 2: Here is my routes as requested

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :graphs do
    resources :trackables do
      resources :points
    end
  end
  root 'graphs#index'
end
```

Models

```
class Graph < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :trackables
end

class Trackable < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :graph
  has_many :points
end

class Point < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trackable
end
```

Graphs and (Updated) Points Controller

```
   class GraphsController < ApplicationController
     def show
       @graph = Graph.find(params[:id])
       @trackables = @graph.trackables.all
     end
   end

  class PointsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @trackable = Trackable.find(:trackable_id)
    @point = @trackable.points.create(params.require(:point).permit(:value))
  end
end
```

views/graphs/show.html.haml

```
- @trackables.each do |trackable|   
  - simple_form_for([trackable, trackable.points.build]) do |f|
    = f.input :value, input_html: { class: "form-control" }
    = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-default"
```

I'm new to all this and my attempt doesn't seem to work. Any help or suggested reading would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Edited my post with the error

Comment: What does `config/routes.rb` look like?

Comment: Edited post to include routes and PointsController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem here is the fact that you are accessing the `Trackable` object directly in the form, but you have no actual path to address the `Trackable` without accessing the `Graph` first. Ie. you have a `graph_trackables_path()` and `graph_trackable_points_path()` methods, but no `trackable_points_path()` method.

Probably you should pass the `@graph` object to the `simple_form_for` call:

```
- simple_form_for([@graph, trackable, trackable.points.build]) do |f|
  ...
```

Otherwise you can define the `Trackable` objects as a separate resource in your `routes.rb` file, but this will probably modify the underlying logics in the controller.

```
resources :graphs do
  resources :trackables do
    resources :points
  end
end

resources :trackables do
  resources :points
end
```

Comment: Thank you, partial fix! The page now loads, but the form is not rendering. I also edited my points controller.  I'm hoping the form for each trackable passes in the trackable_id to params? Not sure though, maybe I need a hidden field?  Either way I don't think that's what is stopping the form from showing.  Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Using the form this way in the `PointsController` you will receive a `params` with both `:trackable_id` and `:graph_id` inside, since you are using a nested path. If you need some other help, let me know!